# Hide ios status bar when "View controller-based status bar appearance"=YES

Tags: ios, statusbar

I need to change status bar style depending on the view controller so in my plist-file "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" is set to **YES**.

And I need to sometimes hide the status bar!

I'm trying to use **setStatusBarHidden** but it seems to work only if "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" is set to **NO** ...

So is there a way to hide the status bar ?

Comment: Override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method in your view controller

Comment: Setting the prefersStatusBarHidden would only work if View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, declare a variable to indicate hidden or not:

```
@interface ExampleViewController
{
    BOOL statusBarHidden;
}
```

**Second**, override UIViewController's method which depends the variable:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return statusBarHidden;
}
```

**Finally**, when you need to **hide** status bar, do:

```
statusBarHidden = YES;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

When you need to **display** status bar again, do:

```
statusBarHidden = NO;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```